# Rounded corners disappear in MultipleDetailViews sample code

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using an UISplitViewController to show multiple detailViews depending on the selection in the root view. To get started I used the [MultipleDetailsViews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code.

When I rotate the iPad to landscape mode and select a DetailView on the RootViewController the inner rounded corners (next to the separator between the Root- and DetailView) disappear.

This happens in Apples sample app out of the box!

What can I do to stop the inner corners from disappearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like iOS 4.2.1 fixed the problem in the simulator and on the device.